# How to access to a button from my viewpager's page

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager

So, I've created a ViewPager who calls two layouts,all I want to do is to add an OnclickListener for a button in the viewpager from one of the two layouts t, I don't know why my Onclick listener is not working. Here's the code:

My Main class:

```
public class hiphopvol2 extends Activity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.slider_hiphop);
    ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.view_pager2);
    viewPager.setAdapter(new CustomPagerAdapter());

}}
```

CustomPagerAdapter(where i created the Onclicklistener for my button):

```
public class CustomPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return 2;
}

@Override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
    return view == ((View) object);
}
@Override
public void destroyItem(View view, int value, Object object) {

    ((ViewPager) view).removeView((View) object);
}

@Override
public Parcelable saveState() {

    return null;
}

@Override
public Object instantiateItem(View collection, int position) {

    LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) collection.getContext()
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    int resultId = 0;
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            resultId = R.layout.hiphopvol2;
            View itemView2 = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.hiphopvol2,null);
            final Button buu=(Button) itemView2.findViewById(R.id.bouton);

            buu.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick (View v) {
                    buu.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN) ;
                }  });

            break;

        case 1:
        default:
            resultId = R.layout.hiphopvol3;
            break;
    }
    View view = layoutInflater.inflate(resultId, null);
    ((ViewPager) collection).addView(view, 0);

    return view;
}}
```

My two layout are a simple xml files with some buttons:
This is where the button is.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bouton"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="hi" />
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm not getting any error but my button "bouton" is not working, any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Show your error Logcat info .

Comment: But i'm not getting any errors in the Logcat, the button is not working but the view pager is fine and i can see the both pages but the buttons there don't work, ty.

Comment: You aren't doing anything with the layout instance that you inflate and setup the `Button` in. That is, `itemView2` is unused. You end up inflating another instance of `hiphopvol2` after the `switch`, but you haven't setup the `Button` in that instance.

Comment: @MikeM. so what should i do exactly, i appreciate your help, ty.

Comment: Something like [this setup](https://pastebin.com/tjmzy8gc) should work for ya.

Comment: Duuuuuuuuuuude, i love you bro <3<3<3<3.

Comment: use interface callback method because you want change in second fragment from first